# Remove extra space/padding/margin while using TextInputLayout and TextInputEditText

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, material-components, material-components-android

I want to remove the extra space shown in following picture.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/00sJc.jpg

Here is my xml:

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/sh_layout_mobile"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_back"
        app:boxBackgroundMode="outline"
        app:hintEnabled="false"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView9">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_phone"
            android:drawableTint="@color/white"
            android:drawableTintMode="multiply"
            android:drawingCacheQuality="high"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
            android:hint="@string/mobile_number"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:paddingRight="0dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textColorHighlight="@color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@color/white"
            android:textColorLink="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

All i want is to minimize or completely remove that top space or margin or padding. I tried myself and tweaked several settings but nothing worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**make styles for editText in which you remove padding**

```
 <style name="styleTextInputEditText" parent="Base.Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText">
    <item name="android:paddingStart">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingEnd">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">0dp</item>
    .....
</style>
```

**and assign it to your textInputLayout editText**

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/yourId"
    style="@style/styleTextInput"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ....>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        style="@style/styleTextInputEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        .... />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: It works, but it is not correct. The `TextInputEditText` style should inherit from `Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.*`. Also check the duplicated answer. You can use a standard *dense style*.